# Common sources of unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-addon

I am trying to debug a JavaScript script that gets read in a Firefox extension and executed. I only can see errors via the Firebug console (my code is invisible to Firebug), and it's reporting a "unterminated string literal."

I checked the line and the lines around it and everything seems fine-parentheses, braces, and quotes are balanced, etc. What are other possible causes that I should be looking for?

Comment: Why mark this as a duplicate? That question has -2 votes and is not really the same question. Looks like someone had nothing else to do.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Most browsers seem to have problems with code like this:

```
var foo = "</script>";
```

In Firefox, Opera and IE8 this results in an unterminated string literal error. Can be pretty nasty when serializing html code which includes scripts.

Comment: This was the cause of my error, even though the script passed JSLint. I changed "</script>" to "</scr"+"ipt>" and that fixed it.

Comment: Ugh. Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: I can't believe this, it fixed the problem. I never would have guessed that in a million years. :(

Comment: Maybe you forgot to encase your script in HTML comments.

Comment: incredible... fixed it for me too.

Comment: Simply escaping the slashes would work too.

Comment: `var setScript = "<scr"+"ipt></script>";` is giving me problem... Any way to fix it?

Comment: Have we been able to determine why the sting `"<script>"` results in an unterminated string literal error? It seems suspicious that breaking up the string into 2 different parts is documented way of fixing this error. (False positive?)

Comment: I was about to gave up on truobleshooting a 400 line innerHTML string that contained several script tags...This worked amazingly well!!!....

Comment: This happened to me when I was copying and pasting from a word editor to Sublime. I accidentally copied a carriage return and didn't even know it was there. I had to advance my cursor along the string to find out where the carriage return was located.

Comment: Holy crap, I can't believe this is the issue! And it's still a problem in 2023 on latest browsers! Amazing.

Answer (score 61):

Look for linebreaks! Those are often the cause.

Comment: I'll second that - I stumbled upon this trying to fix my problem, and all I needed to do was strip my text.

Comment: Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: This fixed it for me, great catch.

Comment: this worked for me too. why why why??

Comment: Exec `dos2unix file.js` to convert linebreaks from CRLF to LF.

Comment: This solved my problem

Comment: Mine was a missing single quote from a json object I was trying to commit.  O_o

Answer (score 26):

I would vote for jamtoday's answer if I had the "reputation"

If your data is coming by way of PHP, this might help

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $str);
```

Comment: FYI, you don't vote "for" any one, single answer on SO. Upvote/downvote any/all answers as you see fit.

Comment: This also fixed my problem, too bad I don't understand *why*.

Comment: @NielsBom It simply removes the line breaks (by replacing them with nothing)

Answer (score 21):

I just discovered that `"<\/script>"` appears to work as well as `"</scr"+"ipt>"`.

Answer (score 12):

Just escape your tag closures or use ascii code

ie

```
<\/script>
```

ie

```
<&#47;script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You might try running the script through [JSLint](http://jslint.com/).

Comment: I've tried that. The output is too noisy. Too many formatting details, and I didn't see anything that would cause the script not to run.

Answer (score 5):

Look for a string which contains an unescaped single qoute that may be inserted by some server side code.

Answer (score 4):

If you've done any cut/paste: some online syntax highlighters will mangle single and double quotes, turning them into formatted quote pairs (matched opening and closing pairs).  (tho i can't find any examples right now)...  So that entails hitting Command-+ a few times and staring at your quote characters

Try a [different font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming)  also, different editors and IDEs use different tokenizers and highlight rules, and JS is one of more dynamic languages to parse, so try opening the file in emacs, vim, gedit (with JS plugins)...  If you get lucky, one of them will show a long purple string running through the end of file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you escaped your forward slashes( / )?
I've had trouble with those before

Answer (score 2):

I've had trouble with angled quotes in the past ( ‘ ) usually from copy and pasting from Word.  Replacing them with regular single quotes ( ' ) does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because you have a line break in your PHP code. If you need line breaks in your alert window message, include it as an escaped syntax at the end of each line in your PHP code. I usually do it the following way:

```
$message = 'line 1.\\n';
$message .= 'line 2.';
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, keep in mind that %0A is the linefeed character URL encoded. It took me awhile to find where there was a linefeed in my offending code.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing helps, look for some uni-code characters like

```
\u2028
```

this may break your string on more than one line and throw this error

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Chromebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads#chromebug)? It's the Firebug for extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try a "binary search". Delete half the code and try again. If the error is still there, delete half the remaining code. If the error is not there, put what you deleted back in, and delete half of that. Repeat.

You should be able to narrow it down to a few line fairly quickly. My experience has been that at this point, you will notice some stupid malformed string.

It may be expedient to perform this on a saved version of the HTML output to the browser, if you're not sure which server-side resource the error is in.

Answer (score 0):

The web page developer guessed wrong about which encoding is used by the viewer's browser.  This can usually be solved by specifying an encoding in the page's header.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the code that comes *before* the line# mentioned by error message. Whatever is unterminated has resulted in something downstream, (the blamed line#), to be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is another issue I find, causes this error. Using a function to trim the whitespace may help.

Answer (score -2):

```
str = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n\r","\r", "\n"), '<br />', stripslashes($str));
```

This should work.

Comment: one more possiblity. in my case it was due to undefined php $_POST variable used in xhttp send method. this resulted in termination of send() parameter string.