# Strange Javascript error with strings

Tags: javascript, string

I'm getting an *"unterminated string literal"* Javascript error with this code:

```
var test = '<script type="text/javascript">var s = document.createElement(\'SCRIPT\');</script></div>';
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm escaping the single quotes, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. However, this code does work:

```
var test = 'var s = document.createElement(\'SCRIPT\');</div>';
```

What would the difference be? I must be missing something here.

Comment: looks like the double quotes?

Comment: I am not getting that error with your code in FireFox, what are you using?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run that. I tested IE6,7,9 and Firefox 3.6.13.

Comment: See this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal

Comment: I just tested in the consoles of Chrome and Firefox with no errors. Maybe give us some more context: is this script being included inline or from a separate file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break up that script tag the old-school way

```
var test = '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">var s = document.createElement(\'SCRIPT\');</scr'+'ipt></div>';
```

Comment: WTF! Why? It gets confused because of the script tag?

Comment: Yep, tries to close the tag early.

Comment: I had answered similar thing but soon got a down vote. Rather than explaining to **down** voters who down vote before they try something out, I thought it was better to delete the answer. +1

Comment: @Sarfraz I'm sorry. Sometimes SO is really fickle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in whatever Javascript parser you're using.

Use double quotes as a workaround instead:

```
var test = '<script type="text/javascript">var s = document.createElement("SCRIPT");</script></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is inline with the rest of the page, you may need to inform the parser that your Javascript code should not be parsed using CDATA.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<![CDATA[
// javascript code goes here, including '<' and '>' characters that could be interpreted as HTML tags
]]>
</script>
```