# unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, string, uploadify

I have a php-script, which uploads mp3-files on my server. I use 'uploadify' for it. There is an event 'onSelect'([documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onselect/)), which called when file has been uploaded. Using it I want to refresh playlist dynamically after each file's uploading.

But my function from 'onselect' field throws an error 'unterminated string literal'. After long searching I make my one-line function instead multi-line(breaklines have been added here for the convenience) and add slashes before double quotes.

```
function() {$('#response').append("
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var flashvars = {url:'./media/audio/users/126/md6xs4cv8ks0.mp3',artist:'Undef', track:'Undef', duration:''};
    var Params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF(\"min.swf\", \"myAlternativeContent1\", \"320\", \"40\", \"9.0.0\", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
<div id="myAlternativeContent1">
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to the other answers, string literals **can** contain line breaks, they just need to be escaped with a backslash like so:

```
var string = "hello\
world!";
```

However, this does not create a line break in the string, as it must be an explicit `\n` escape sequence. This would technically become `helloworld`. Doing

```
var string = "hello"
+ "world"
```

would be much cleaner

Comment: "String literals can contain line breaks" "This does not create a line break in the string". You're right about `\\`, but if you're going to word your answer in a way that tries to devalue other answers, you should be absolutely certain that yours is of the highest possible calibre.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with my post. The string **literal** contains the line break. The **string** object that results from it does not.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax highlighting right there in your post makes it clear: you have unescaped quotes in your `<div>` block (and you forgot the end of your script).

Anyway, string literals in Javascript can't span multiple lines.

Instead of:

```
alert("lol
       wtf");
```

write:

```
alert("lol" +
      "wtf");
```

You might also consider breaking apart the `</script>` substring, [which has been known to cause parsing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal):

```
"</scr" + "ipt>"
```

---

<sup>(Strictly speaking, to be equivalent, the second example above would have a `\n` and some spaces after `lol`, but that shouldn't matter in your case of writing HTML markup.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for comment about quotes.
About multiline: they have been added here for the convenience. Source is oneline

Comment: @dark: Well it's hardly a convenience when it completely breaks the question. The first paragraph still stands (look in your `div`).

Answer (score 0):

Could be the presence of the `</script>`. Try escaping one or more of those characters (i.e. use `<\/script>` instead)