# org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break while using executeScript through Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break while using executeScript through Selenium

`executeScript()` is working perfect with single line *String* as an example:

```
String myText = "80120804076";
```

But when I am trying to send a multiline *String* `JavascriptException` is raised.

- Code trials:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class send_large_text {

      static WebDriver driver;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://translate.shell.com/");
          //String myText = "80120804076";
          String myText = "No, there is no way to hide the console window of the chromedriver.exe \n"
              + "in the .NET bindings without modifying the bindings source code. This is seen \n"
              + "as a feature of the bindings, as it makes it very easy to see when your code \n"
              + "hasn\'t correctly cleaned up the resources of the ChromeDriver, since the console window \n"
              + "remains open. In the case of some other languages, if your code does not properly clean up \n"
              + "the instance of ChromeDriver by calling the quit() method on the WebDriver object, \n"
              + "you can end up with a zombie chromedriver.exe process running on your machine.";
          (   (JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value=\'" + myText + "\';", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("textarea.form-control#translateText"))));
      }
  }
  ```
- Error Observed:

  ```
  1544184402064   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.b4OAHY7RViE6"
  1544184406841   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 11919
  1544184406988   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
  Dec 07, 2018 5:36:47 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
  Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
  System info: host: 'ATECHM-03', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
  Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 63.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 5620, moz:profile: C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 6.2, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
  Session ID: 31ac155f-8f03-4adf-bc7b-a778f1235351
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:485)
      at demo.send_large_text.main(send_large_text.java:25)
  ```

I have been through the related discussions:

- Java:

  - [Java multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)
- JavaScript:

  - [How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript)
  - [javascript Syntax error : Unterminated string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256320/javascript-syntax-error-unterminated-string-literal)
  - [Common sources of unterminated string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal)
  - [unterminated string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876264/unterminated-string-literal)

Reference: [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)

Still no clue where I am going wrong. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1) added an extra slash before every `\n` to make it `\\n`

2) added extra slash before apostrphne `hasn\'t` to make it `hasn\\'t`

```
"No, there is no way to hide the console window of the chromedriver.exe \\n"
                + "in the .NET bindings without modifying the bindings source code. This is seen \\n"
                + "as a feature of the bindings, as it makes it very easy to see when your code \\n"
                + "hasn\\'t correctly cleaned up the resources of the ChromeDriver, since the console window \\n"
                + "remains open. In the case of some other languages, if your code does not properly clean up \\n"
                + "the instance of ChromeDriver by calling the quit() method on the WebDriver object, \\n"
                + "you can end up with a zombie chromedriver.exe process running on your machine.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this method:

```
String myText = {"No, there is no way to hide the console window of the chromedriver.exe",
                 "in the .NET bindings without modifying the bindings source code. This is seen",
                 "as a feature of the bindings, as it makes it very easy to see when your code",
                 "hasn\'t correctly cleaned up the resources of the ChromeDriver, since the console window",
                 "remains open. In the case of some other languages, if your code does not properly clean up",
                 "the instance of ChromeDriver by calling the quit() method on the WebDriver object,",
                 "you can end up with a zombie chromedriver.exe process running on your machine."}.join("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks. Shows an error as `The method join(String) is undefined for the type 
  send_large_text
 - Syntax error on token ".", ; expected`