# AJAX Unexpected Token / Unterminated String Literal

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

The page I am working with is: http://glenwoodia.com/business-directory

I am having issues getting the pagination functionality to work.  When you click on one of the numbers (the 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 at the top), it is supposed to dynamically pull that set of businesses and display them on the page.  However, in Google Chrome I get an 'unexpected token illegal' error, and in firefox / IE I get an 'unterminated string literal' error.

The specific PHP code I have to process the AJAX should, in my mind, take care of any rogue characters that could be causing the issue:

```
    $listings = trim(strip_tags(str_replace("'","\'",stripslashes(bizdir_directory("",@$v["offset"])))));
    $response = "clearMessage();
        document.getElementById('bizdir_directory').innerHTML = '{$listings}';
    ";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `'` isn't the *only* character that can break your JavaScript string. Newlines in your data could also produce the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead of those ugly str_replaces -- it takes care of encoding just about anything that would otherwise be invalid in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = <?php echo json_encode("single quote ', double quote \", new
lines"); ?>;
</script>
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = "single quote ', double quote \", new\r\nlines";
</script>
```

I think your code can be written like this:

```
$listings = json_encode(trim(bizdir_directory("", $v["offset"])));
// #1: note that json_encode does not trim the input string
$response = "
    clearMessage();
    document.getElementById('bizdir_directory').innerHTML = {$listings};
"; // #2: note that {$listings} is not enclosed inside quotes
```

Comment: `$listings = addslashes(json_encode(bizdir_directory("", @$v["offset"])));`

produces output, but it has no formatting.

Comment: You don't need `addslashes` because the function (i) adds all necessary slashes (ii) encloses the string inside `"`. See revised answer.

Comment: Yes, at first it didn't work, but that's because I tried enclosing it in ' in the javascript.  Making that change worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = "clearMessage();";
$response .= "document.getElementById('bizdir_directory').innerHTML = '{$listings}';";
```

Comment: so it JS Error, you need to break $listings variable in multiple lines.

Comment: How do you propose I do that? And I guess the important question is, why? The other parts of that page that use AJAX function just fine, and pull businesses from the database, without returning any errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal

Answer (score 0):

Just a random question, but should:

```
'{$listings}'
```

not be

```
{$listings}
```

instead? Without the single quotes? I'm assuming that well-formed JSON code is being returned - apologies for not having a chance to look at the URL you provided - I might be way off the mark here ;)

Comment: The single quotes are necessary for the javascript, as $listings is a string.

Comment: In PHP this value is inside the double quotes, so the value is actually evaluated. The single quotes are just part of the outputted string.

Comment: Ooooo I see...have you thought about using PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function at all? I know managing quotes inside javascript variable passing can feel like pulling teeth ;P

Answer (score 0):

The response when clicking on a link is JavaScript that is [`eval()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#JavaScript)'d

It is setting the innerHTML of an element without surrounding it with quotes. You just need to quote the value, for example:

```
"clearMessage();document.getElementById('bizdir_directory').innerHTML = 'foo bar'"
```

instead of

```
"clearMessage();document.getElementById('bizdir_directory').innerHTML = foo bar"
```

The response I am getting when clicking page 2 is

```
"clearMessage();document.getElementById('bizdir_directory').innerHTML = Pages:&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;&nbsp;6&nbsp;&nbsp;7Central Realty, LLCVickie Gerdes / Greg Patterson331 West Thornton Ave.St. Louis, MO 63119314-862-5557gerdesv@central-realty.comReal Estate / Rental Property.Chat Mobility - EmersonTerry Gray404 HowlandP.O. Box 289Emerson, Iowa 515331-800-944-5526http://www.chatmobility.comtgray@chatmobility.comCommunication.Chat Mobility - GlenwoodSandy Dornburgh906 South Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3020http://www.chatmobility.comsdornburgh@chatmobility.comCommunication.City of GlenwoodBrian Kissel107 South Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-4717city.hall@mchsi.comGovernment.Classic Cafe, LLCAlicia Bartley315 Main StreetMalvern, Iowa 51551712-624-8082http://www.classiccafeandcatering.combartleya14@hotmail.comRestaurant/Catering.Cohron Ready Mix, LLCSteve McCraken10001 192nd StreetCouncil Bluffs, Iowa 51503712-527-4696Concrete Company.Common Ground MinistryJon McNeel113 Center StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534402-525-9642jmcneel@cqmglenwood.orgMinistry, youth group.Country TireTom Collinson611 South Hazel StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3621http://www.countrytire.biz/glenwoodfirestone.htmglenwoodfirestone@yahoo.comAutomotive Repair.Crash and BurnsCandice Burns1002 Lincoln StreetMalvern, Iowa 51551402-679-6927cburns.computer.repair@gmail.comComputer repair.Croatt Heating &amp; Air Conditioning, LLCMathew and Jodi Croatt23203 Kane Ave.Glenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3455croatthvac@gmail.comFull service heating and air conditioning.Crouch, Richard &amp; BarbCrouch, Richard &amp; Barb59629 280th StreetMalvern, Iowa 51551712-524-8933Crobertson@millscoia.usIndividuals.Culligan Water ConditioningGlenn Robinson / Bill Cunard113 South 9th StreetP.O. 445Missouri Valley, Iowa 51555712-642-2695http://www.culligan.comglennculligan@yahoo.comWater conditioning.Davies AmphitheaterGordon &amp; Lori Woodrow301 North WalnutGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3545http://www.glenwoodnet.com/daviesg.woodrow@mchsi.comRecreation.Davis, Dick &amp; JudyDavis, Dick &amp; Judy1007 4th StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-9527rrjjdavis@gmail.comIndividuals.DeShawne Bird-Sell PLC Attorney At LawDeShawne Bird-Sell417 Sharp SteetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-4026deshawne@aol.comLaw firm.Don&#039;s FurnitureDon Malcom419 Sharp StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-4809setterrw@aol.comRetail.Dr. Barry JoseDr. Barry Jose1601 Ave. DGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-323-5213Individuals.Dr. Robert FryzekDr. Robert Fryzek14 North WalnutGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-9135Medical, general family practice.Edward JonesRon Hanson908 South Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3520http://www.edwardjones.comron.hanson@edwardjones.comInvestment Planning/Investing.El Portel Mexican RestaurantMartin Barajas612 Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-4014Restaurants.Embray, DevinEmbray, Devin103 CentralGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-9034Individuals.Evans Equipment Company, E.E.C., IncorporatedJeff &amp; Michelle Evans1305 South Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-1440http://www.evansrental.comRental equipment.Exclusive PaintingJamie &amp; Stephanie Todd25880 Noyes Ave.Glenwood, Iowa 51534402-740-9099Painting Service.Farm Bureau Insurance &amp; Financial ServicesJohn Gregory302 South Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3153http://www.agentjohngregory.comInsurance and financial services.Feed EnergyJoe Liddick / Paul Knockel20159 Kelting Ave.P.O. Box 130Pacific Junction, Iowa 51561712-655-8293http://www.feedenergy.comIndustries.FFG Consulting, LLCMark FordP.O. Box 529Glenwood, Iowa 51534712-309-6336http://www.FFGroupConsulting.comConsulting.First National BankDoug Meggison102 South Locust StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3171dmeggison@fnni.comBanks / Financial.Five Star Quality Care, Inc.Nate Parks114 East GreenGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-4841http://www.5sqc.comnparks@5sqc.comHuman Services.Fountains Ballroom, Inc.Marty &amp; Erin Williams51496 - 230th StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-526-2030http://www.thefountainsballroom.comWeddings, conferences, special occasions, photography and catering.Garden TreasuresRyan &amp; Connie Bichel22309 221st StreetGlenwood, Iowa 51534712-527-3602http://www.ryansgardentreasures.comryan.bichel@yahoo.comFull service Garden Center, statuary, birdbathes, benches, fountains, landscape supplies, mulch, rock, sand, soil and so much more.Pages:&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;&nbsp;6&nbsp;&nbsp;7;"
```

in which you can see the missing quotes.

Comment: When I debugged it, there was no quotes. I have added the response I was seeing.