# Using JS within PHP for an if window.width issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm wanting to `echo` some code based on whether the user is on a mobile device (less than 768px) or larger.

I have done the following:

```
            <?php  
              if ( is_home() ) {
            ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
              if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                  document.write("<?php echo my_shortcode("[mobile-slider]"); ?>");
              } else {
                  document.write("<?php echo my_shortcode("[desktop-slider]"); ?>");
              }
              </script>
            <?php                    
            } else {
              //do the stuff for the other pages

            } ?>
```

But now when the homepage renders it displays `"); } else { document.write("` then the homepage slider and then `"); }`. Any idea why?

JS error

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
>
> document.write('

HTML Output - Seems to be adding a line break which I think is breaking the script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
document.write("
<!--slider-->
```

Comment: my_shortcode should be do_shortcode., my_shortcode is not a wordpress function !

Comment: It is exactly that :) Just using the above wp code as an example and didn't want to make this WP related.

Comment: Okey did you check for any js errors in console while loading the page ?

Comment: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal 
document.write('
`

Comment: @wordpresser any idea on this error? Updated the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal see here

Comment: why are there quotes around php tags? are you trying to echo something from php, if so then @Vincent has the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
"<?php echo my_shortcode("[mobile-slider]"); ?>"
```

CHANGE TO

```
"<?php echo my_shortcode('[mobile-slider]'); ?>"
                         ^               ^  // changed quotes here
```

or escape quotes

```
"<?php echo my_shortcode(\"[mobile-slider]\"); ?>"
```

Comment: I tried that and it still did the same thing :( That's why I tried using double quotes because the PHP executes regardless. Thanks @TusharGupta

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.write(<?php echo "\"[mobile-slider]\""; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your quotes are definately off, as others have mentioned, your inner quotes must be different from the outer ones, or escaped.

Is it possible for you to run your php function in the main document(outside of the javascript), then choose to show/hide/alter its contents with the javascript?

If that's not possible, try calling your function directly, instead of through the do_shortcode hook.

As a final alternative, you may need to use an ajax call here. I don't know that you're able to call shortcodes the way you're attempting to do here.