# Intellij Idea Ecmascript Harmony modules syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, intellij-idea, ecmascript-harmony

Im using Intellij Idea for some ES Harmony app. With [modules syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3amodules) I want my IDE to do not highlight this as errors:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

I have turned ES Harmony support in project settings, but it does not help.

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea of which version you have in which it's _not_ working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case somebody here is still experiencing Issues with ECMAScript 6, you have to enable it in IntelliJ.

[image]

and after activating ecmascript, set it as JavaScript Language Version:

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to disable the "unterminated statement" message?

Comment: I don't know if there is, but according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal it seems a bad idea to do so, if possible.

Comment: I only get it when leaving out semicolons, which most Node-based templates (e.g. Electron) do.

Answer (score 1):

Try an EAP version, it technically has support but it is not currently working for me.