# Trying ES6 style import gives 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write a javascript test in intellij for which I need to import some dependancies and I want to use ES6 style import statements but getting error

```sh
/usr/local/bin/node /workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
--ui bdd --reporter "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2019.1/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js"
tests/*.test.js /workspace/rr-sample/tests/App.test.js:3
import chai from 'chai'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1091:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at /workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:334:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:331:14)
    at Mocha.run (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:809:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:108:16)
    at exports.runMocha (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:142:13)
    at Object.exports.handler (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:292:3)
    at Object.runCommand (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1087:28)
    at Object.parse (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:68:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/rr-sample/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:67:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

What exactly is the issue? I found this link (and others) http://xahlee.info/js/js_import_export.html which tells you how to fix this error but in another context which doesn't help me, and it doesn't explain what the problem is.

In case it is helpful here is the code I am using.

```
//const chai = require("chai");
import chai from 'chai'

const React = require("react");
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('how it works first-time test', () => {
  it('checks equality', () => {

    const val = false;
    expect(val).to.be.false;
  });

});
```

Comment: _“it doesn't explain what the problem is”_ — it does explicitly say _“If your code uses `import` or `export`, then it must be loaded as module.”_ along the part where it says that you must use `type="module"`. Have you seen [Intellij Idea Ecmascript Harmony modules syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21609025/4642212)?

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way to run Mocha tests written in ES6 is compiling them on-the-fly using Mocha `--require @babel/register` option (see https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation#what-should-i-use-instead-then). Of course, you need to make sure to install the corresponding modules and set up the `.babelrc` accordingly

*package.json:*

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/register": "^7.7.4",
...
}
```

*.babelrc:*

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image]

See also https://dev.to/bnorbertjs/my-nodejs-setup-mocha--chai-babel7-es6-43ei

Comment: Important for me was the Extra Mocha Options

Comment: it's Mocha run configuration, you can find it in **Run > Edit Configurations...**

Comment: Worked for me, didn't use the config he has in the screenshot

Comment: Dogshit solution way too much complexity

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem when updating one of my ts libraries to es6 modules instead of commonjs. After the change in the tsconfig.json my `npm run test` produced the mentioned error.

```
import chai from 'chai'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I **solved it without babel** by adding an own tsconfig file just for testing.

tsconfig.testing.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

To run the tests via script in package.json

```
"test": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.testing.json\" mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts",
```

(cross-env to set the env variable os independent)

Comment: Note that `cross-env` is in maintenance mode

Comment: @pixel, can you please add how this is relevant, thank you

Comment: some people might want to stick to up to date / actively maintained libs - my comment was intended for those people

Comment: Maintenance mode basically means no new features will be added, just bugfixes if necessary. It stays relevant for the usecase above. See more info and find alternatives at  https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/257

Comment: Did it not work without the tsconfig change? I just had the same issue and this script corrected it without any additional changes: "test": "mocha -r ts-node src/**/*.test.ts"

Comment: cross-env is only needed if you're running Windows.

Comment: cross-env can be a solution if ANYONE, working on the project, is running windows

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get this working by adding a .mocharc.yaml file at the source of my project with the following:

```
require: '@babel/register'
```

source: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/tree/master/packages/babel

Comment: This was enough for me to be able to run in webstorm by right clicking on `it` and `describe`

Comment: This solved issue of `import` but now having another issue of test coverage dropped from 97% to 10%

Comment: @Ashish Kamble 

If you don't import any file you'll have full coverage. It's like if you don't write any code you won't have any bugs

Answer (score 2):

The cause of my issue was - an **old version of Mocha**, in fact any <6.0.0, even when the 'require: @babel/register' was configured. I updated Mocha to 9.0.0, I also updated Babel libraries to the latest and the problem was solved.

As it is also suggested in the Mocha [docs](https://mochajs.org/#-require-module-r-module), use config file, like '.mocharc.js', where you have to declare required Babel dependancy like in [this](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js) example:

.mocharc.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  require: '@babel/register',
  ...
}
```

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0"
    ...
    "mocha": "^9.0.0",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_import_code_statements):

> https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_import_code_statements

So you have to ensure execute the script as an es module.

e.g. Execute the script using [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) instead of Nodejs to enable the es6 or newer.

Comment: The question is ask about to use Typescript in Mocha. Not in the App

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For me, I was not able to run it via inline debug option in intellj. So I set extra mocha option and this solved the issue.

```
--compilers js:babel-core/register
```

Also, to run via terminal

```
npx mocha  --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

Comment: `--compilers` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is one edge case that can cause this error that is worth mentioning, because I lost quite a bit of my life to troubleshooting it. I had accidentally done a `yarn install` inside of my src folder. My unit test command from package.json is:

```
"test:unit": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha \"src/**/*.spec.js\"",
```

And the error message had a subtle hint in it that took me a while to see (i.e. the file causing this import error was inside of src/node_modules) :

```
/Users/jeff/src/my-proj/src/node_modules/camel-case/dist.es2015/index.spec.js:1
import { camelCase, camelCaseTransformMerge } from ".";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
... (omitted for brevity) ...
```

Once I deleted the node_modules folder that was out of place (and left the one that's in the root of my project), mocha began to run MY tests, and not someone else's, and the error message went away!