# What is the correct setup to support es6 modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have created an app with `create-react-app` and added typescript. After finishing app modules I wanted to do some unites test I have installed mocha and chai:  `npm install --save-dev mocha chai`.

in my pakacge.json I have updated test script to `"test": "mocha src/test/*"`. After using an import in my test file

```
import {assert} from 'chai'
import {File} from "../components/File"
```

I run into an issue

```
import {assert} from 'chai'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have searched a lot and tried a ton of answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042716/trying-es6-style-import-gives-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) but still run into the same issue -_- And I am confused whether I need to install babel? Here is my `package.json` any explanation

```json
{
  ...
    "dependencies": {
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
      "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
      "@types/classnames": "^2.2.11",
      "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
      "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
      "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
      "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
      "classnames": "^2.2.6",
      "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
      "react": "^17.0.1",
      "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
      "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
      "typescript": "^4.2.3",
      "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.testing.json\" mocha src/test/*",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/chai": "^4.2.16",
      "@types/mocha": "^8.2.2",
      "chai": "^4.3.4",
      "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
      "mocha": "^8.3.2"
    }
  }
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

How could I set up everything correctly?

Comment: For the error, change it to: import assert from 'chai' and you may also need to add "es2015" to your lib in tsconfig.json, try it and let me know

Comment: No it does not fix the error the problem is mocha and chai does not support es6

Comment: You said mocha doesn't support es6 but in your lib in tsconfig I see you're suing es5, no?

Comment: FOr mocha, here's how I usually use it: import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';     Here's an example: describe('add function', () => {

  it('should add two and two', () => {
    const result = add(2,2);
    expect(result).to.equal(4);
  });

  it('should add -2 and two', () => {
    const result = add(-2,2);
    expect(result).to.equal(0);
  });

});

Comment: do u add babel for it how do u run the test? what are things do u add so mocha understand es6 models.

Comment: Here's how I run the test: in the scripts section, I have use this: "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register tests/sampleTest.ts", with node/register . PS: This is the way I test in Typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 02 options

1. **using `ts-mocha`** the short way => `npm install --save-dev ts-mocha`

> Mocha thin wrapper that allows running TypeScript tests with TypeScript runtime (ts-node) to get rid of compilation complexity. All Mocha features are available without any limitation. [See documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha).

use this ts configuration for the test `tsconfig.testing.json`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src/test/*"]
}
```

> This a basic configuration you can update it according to your need

Add script to `package.json` scripts:  `"test-ts": "ts-mocha -p tsconfig.testing.json src/test/*"`

> Well you should pay attention for importing text files that may run into issues. it will lead to **token errors** so move them to another files and make sure your `utils` functoins to be pure functions since you run unit test.

> Another important note: You should set `"module": "commonjs"` to fix conflict issues, like yours `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

2. **use normal `mocha` with `ts-node/register`** for TypeScript execution. [Check the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

- you should install `ts-node` and `cross-env` to use the new `tsconfig.testing.json`.
- This is a simple configuration for the `tsconfig.testing.json`. Note you should add to the up configuration `moduleResolution` to `node` Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383049/typescript-esnext-compiler-option-destroys-es6-import-from-external-lib) for more details. Add the path to your declaration types if there is any to avoid errors of type `error TS2304: Cannot find name "type_name"`.
- Add script to `package.json` scripts: `cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.testing.json\" mocha -r ts-node/register src/test/*`

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules/",
    "./dist/"
  ], 
  "files": [
    "path_to_your_types_declaration"
  ]
}
```