# Change line-spacing / line height in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, editor

I know this has been already posted but quite time ago, so I ask again in case something changed: is there a way to set **line-spacing / line-height** in Eclipse text editor? The default settings doesn't seem to me very readable - see the difference: http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/3315/eclipseyh.png (generally Eclipse renders fonts weirdly, they look much better in gvim).

I've read the tip that I could manually edit some font and modify its attributes but that seems a little bit over-complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change line height / line spacing in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014454/how-can-i-change-line-height-line-spacing-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure this feature request has had much traction for the past 10 years:

[bug 26765: Add option for line spacing](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26765).

Comment: @Z.Neeson indeed (time flies...). Note that this bug has only 18 votes.

Comment: @VonC registration required to vote is the reason y has 18 votes only I suppose.