# Hide Horizontal Scrollbars [Juno/Kepler/Luna]

Tags: eclipse, scrollbar, hide, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

As per the solution provided in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186089/hide-status-bar-or-progress-bar-in-eclipse) we can get back some screen real estate from Eclipse.

However, when working with multiple editor tabs (e.g. in a quadrant layout) the ever present horizontal scrollbars (even when there is no text extending beyond viewing area!) are a waste of valuable coding space, not to mention, hideous.

Have tried various CSS hacks in eclipse default_gtk.css (on Linux here) all to no avail; it appears that the ScrollBar widget is not modifiable via CSS.

This [bug thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420238) on saving space in Eclipse indicates something is in the works for Luna, but the developers seem split, some not caring about scrollbars or any wasted space (assuming everyone has huge monitors), and others preferring a clean and lean UI.

Anyway, if anyone has leads for how to hide scrollbars in Eclipse >= 4.2, do chime in! It's IMO the missing UI "feature" of Eclipse as you can strip out everything else, almost have max screen real estate available for code...just these damn scrollbars o_O

Comment: I think this does depend a lot on what the native controls used by SWT support. On the Mac, for example, scroll bars are not displayed. If  the SWT control on Linux supports turning off the scroll bars it should be possible to write a CSS property handler to set it.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the tip, can you point me to any resources for setting a custom CSS property handler? (or provide as an answer and I'll upvote).

Answer (score 1):

I think this does depend a lot on what the native controls used by SWT support. On the Mac, for example, scroll bars are not displayed.

**If** the SWT control on Linux supports turning off the scroll bars it should be possible to write a CSS property handler to set it. I do something similar on the Mac to set the scroll bar 'knob style' for trees and tables.

See my any answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345028/increased-line-height-for-consolas-font-in-eclipse) which shows how to write a CSS property handler in a plugin for `StyledText` which could be adapted.

Comment: +1, thanks I'll give the plugin approach a shot. BTW, if you or anyone else cares about stripping out extra whitespace in Eclipse interface, chime in on the bug report listed in my question.