# How do you modify spacing between characters and their proportions in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, font-size, typography

These settings can be changed in a advanced character options in Word 2013.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change line height / line spacing in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014454/how-can-i-change-line-height-line-spacing-in-eclipse)

Comment: That deals with line spacing. I am talking about character spacing.

Comment: Eclipse is not a word processor and does not provide any character spacing options.

Comment: Ok thanks sorry for my ignorance on the matter for now. How about creating a custom font from the existing one but with different spacing options? Once cloned, I could set it as default font for the editor.

Answer (score 0):

AS @greg-449 said in a comment above, Eclipse is not a word processor. If you don't like the font, choose a different font that has spacing more to your liking. **Preferences** > **General** > **Appearance** > **Colors and Fonts**.

[image]

There are lots of good fonts for programming. For example, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming) on the subject or [this Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=programming+fonts).