# Do N-Space font variants exist?

Tags: fonts

Programmers often fall back on **mono**space font variants for legibility, however some programmers blogs I read are starting to laud variable width fonts.

It seems to me that the best of both worlds would be a font where all character widths are small multiples of the space width (so M might be three or four spaces)

Does anyone know if such a font exists, and if so if a variant is available for free?

Comment: Should it be a community wiki? I guess its only tangentially related to programming.

Comment: Can you add links to these blogs?  Personally, I would have major difficulties reading such fonts.  Most programming font discussions I've read deal with choosing the most readable font, virtually all of which are monospace.

Comment: What are these blogs you're talking about? What's wrong with monospace fonts? if it works, don't change it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485174/programming-fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they should be possible but apparently no one knows of any.

Answer (score 1):

We can make this a programming question by answering it as such.

In pseudo code:

```
For each of your installed fonts{
    spacewidth = widthof(space);
    For each character in the current font{
        width[charcode] = widthof[charcode];
    }

    print standarddeviation(spacewidth, width);
}
```