# Courier New with slashed 0 (zero) and distinct 1 (one)

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended Fonts for Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming)

Courier New is perfect (for me) for programming.

Except that it really needs a slashed 0 (zero) and distinct 1 (one) vs l (letter l).

Is there a recompile of the font with these features?

(edit: this question is about **Courier New** :)

(edit 2: Stack Overflow failed me here, I specifically asked about Courier New, I don't care about other programming fonts. Perhaps I needed to really make that clear in the question.)

Comment: This question covers the same ground: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming

Comment: re: edit 2 - that isn't how stack overflow works. you ask your question then everyone tells you what is wrong with it. for answers you have to use a different resource. ;-)

Comment: The answer to your question is no.  If someone compiles Courier New with a slashed zero, then it would need to be named something else.  The [Courier family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_(typeface)#Variants) has many fonts, perhaps one of them (like Courier Code) will suit your needs.

Comment: Indeed Courier New (bold) reads best on Win.
I've tried many things to edit fonts with free tools, unfortunately it
seems that it is, hmm, impossible, or crashes things. IDK, probably has something to do with the word "proprietary" and invisible forces. OTOH, I never had any significant problems with 0O, but probably a bit with l1. Also I use proportional font where possible.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas), which is similar to Courier New but makes these distinctions.
It also makes much better use of ClearType.

It's included with Vista and with Office 2007, and with the free [PowerPoint Viewer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=048DC840-14E1-467D-8DCA-19D2A8FD7485&displaylang=en).

Comment: +1 for Consolas.  To my dismay though it looks like garbage over remote desktop...

Comment: @Jason — Consolas was designed for sub-pixel rendering.  If you change your RDC color settings to 32-bit, enable the "Font smoothing" feature, and are connecting to a box with ClearType enabled, it *should* look the same as anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

When I got tired of Courier New I started to use [Triskweline](http://www.netalive.org/tinkering/triskweline/), and now I love it; despite being a bitmap font, it's quite nice, and it offers easily recognizable characters, especially for the most "problematic" ones (1/I/l, O/0, ...).

Moreover, it doesn't look like garbage as Consolas if ClearType is not available/disabled.

By the way, here are some other "alternative" programming fonts:

- [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html), my new other favorite one;
- [Dina](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Jibz/Dina/index.html);
- [Proggy](http://www.proggyfonts.com/index.php?menu=download);
- [Envy](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released);
- [Some other fonts](http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/AlternativeFonts);
- (again) [Triskweline](http://www.netalive.org/tinkering/triskweline/).

Comment: +1 for Dina.  Is my favorite.

Comment: Also a fan of Triskweline, made a version of it with edits for better code readability - https://github.com/ideasman42/triskweline-code-font

Comment: Woa, a blast from the past! So much time has passed, currently my go-to monospace font is *DejaVu Sans Mono*, less original but easier on eyes and scales fine on current high-resolution monitors. Still, nice to see Triskweline still alive. :-)