# Dreamweaver CS5 Color theme?

Tags: dreamweaver

How do I change the default coloring/fonts in Dreamweaver CS5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code color: Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences, Code Color category, select that document type you want to edit and then click the Edit Coloring Scheme button. Color away.

Since you give no clue as to what you'd actually like to see in your question, if you happen to like a "dark" theme, then check out the instructions on the following page: http://www.sramekdesign.com/dreamweaver/dark-coding-colorization-for-dreamweaver/

Fonts: Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences, Fonts category. You should be able to choose from any font that is installed on your system. For font recommendations see: [Recommended Fonts for Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming)

Comment: Code coloring is done on a document type by type basis, you may have to apply the color changes to the JSP file type by going to: Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences -> Code Coloring, Select JSP, and then click the Edit Coloring scheme button, change away.

Answer (score 7):

I created a Dreamweaver color theme editor, it lets you start with the default theme or a dark theme I made that's designed to make it easy to transition to a dark theme.

You can edit 18 different colors, and then you can download an xml file that replaces the current one. It takes care of all the redundant color settings. It also has instructions for how to install the theme. Super easy.

Try it out! [**http://inorganik.net/dw-color-theme-editor**](http://inorganik.net/dw-color-theme-editor)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a dark colour theme based on the 'minimal Theme' for TextMate. It's optimised for HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP.

To download: https://gist.github.com/998843

Use the same installation instructions outlined in the link Danilo sent, but set the background colour to #25221C.