# Blank space is not displayed the same in the console output and in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing code to automate the code of PLSQL basic structure.
So i have a list which holds the parameters, example as below,

```
 pv_student_name IN  VARCHAR2
 pn_number       OUT NUMBER
```

So the parameters must be properly aligned as above, So I have written a procedure (method) in `c#` which takes plain input and align the parameters and returns a list with properly aligned parameters.

But When I print in the **Console** using `System.Console.WriteLine` then the parameters are aligned properly But when I see the parameters in a `List Box` the parameters are not aligned properly , though the spaces are added.

Below is the alignment code.

```
//Alignment of parameters logic 
private List<string> alignParameters(List<string> nonAligned_parameters){
    List<string> alignedParamtersList = new List<string>();

    List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
    List<string> inOutList = new List<string>();
    List<string> dataTypeList = new List<string>();

    foreach (string parameter in nonAligned_parameters)
    {
        string[] param = parameter.Split(' ');

        int count = 1;
        foreach (string word in param) 
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                parameterList.Add(word.Trim());
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                inOutList.Add(word.Trim());
            }
            else if (count == 3) {
                dataTypeList.Add(word.Trim());
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    // find the longest string in the list 
    int maxLength = parameterList.Max(x => x.Length);

    //aligning the parameters
    int numberOfElements= parameterList.Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) 
    {
        string param = parameterList[i].ToString().Trim();
        string inOut = inOutList[i].ToString().Trim();
        string dataType = dataTypeList[i].ToString().Trim();

        int requiredSpace = maxLength - param.Length + 1;

        string spaces = new string(' ', requiredSpace);
        string spc = "";
        if ("OUT".Equals(inOut)) {
            spc = " ";
        }
        else if ("IN".Equals(inOut)) {
            spc = "  ";
        }

        string alignedParameter = param +
                                  spaces +
                                  inOut +
                                  spc +
                                  dataType;

        // adding aligned parameters in aligned parameter list to be returned
        alignedParamtersList.Add(alignedParameter);
    }

    return alignedParamtersList;
}
```

Below is the procedure where it is called, when we add a new parameter then the parameter is added, aligned and then populated back in the `ListBox`

```
private void button_AddParameter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string error = "N";

    //validation code here

    if ("N".Equals(error)) {
        parameterName = label_paramPrefix.Text +
                        textBox_parameterName.Text +" "+
                        combo_InOut.SelectedItem.ToString()+" "+
                        combo_DataType.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    parameterList.Add(parameterName);

    // Align the parameters
    parameterListAligned = alignParameters(parameterList);

    // populating parameter list in GUI with fresh aligned parameters
    listBox_parameter.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string parameters in parameterListAligned)
    {
        listBox_parameter.Items.Add(parameters);
        System.Console.WriteLine("param" + parameters);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that even if the **Console** outputs the parameters aligned properly, the `ListBox` doesn't.

Can you guys please help me with this, I need those parameters to appear aligned in the `ListBox` as well.

Screen shot of the application where we can see the parameters not aligned in the `ListBox` is attached. and console output screenshot is also attached below that.

[image: Screenshot parameters not appearing aligned in ListBox]

[image: Proper alignment in the console]

Comment: Your app uses a variable width font and thus the width of each letter is not the same. (as in W vs I )  You need to change your font to a Fixed one or use a ListView using columns to display each part of your output

Comment: @Steve Thanks , But i am new to .net (i work on java, my lead asked me to make the same application in .net which i made in java) , So can you please let me know how to change the font which is getting displayed on the ListBox (Also i need to change that in a RichTextBox) as i will be displaying it there as well. Also can you please let me know how to use a LisView using column (This i didn't understood at all what you meant) , Sorry for the stupid kind of questions i am asking. :-)

Comment: I don't understand a thing here. You have showed an interface of a desktop application (WinForms or WPF?) but marked your question with the ASP.NET tag. Can you clarify which kind of application are we talking about here?

Comment: @Steve I am using visual basics to make this, and the language is C# . 
Its a desktop application.

Comment: Well, then you just click on the ListBox in your designer then look at the Properties window, you will find a Property for the Font and you can change from there using a Fixed Width font http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming A ListView is just another control that you can use instead of a ListBox. An answer how to use a ListView is probably too big here. Just search on the net for ListView in Details mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use a [`monospace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font, you can change the `font` of a `listview` from its properties windows (choose the `listview` in visual studio and click `F4`) and then change the font to something like 'Courier'.